# Send message to other devices in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm migrating from the deprecated Google Cloud Messaging to the latest version of "Google Play Services". 
Before sending messages to other devices using the "Sender" class was gcm.jar.

Example: sender.send (msg, reg-id-device, retries);

Now I read that to send the message is required "GoogleCloudMessaging" class, and do not know how to send the reg-id-device I want. 
I found this:

gcm.send (SENDER_ID + "@ gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);

I do not know where I should put the "reg-id-device".

Answer (score 0):

Sender class is in gcm-server.jar and it's not deprecated.

The deprecated library gcm.jar is the client side library.
It is replaced by GoogleCloudMessaging class of the Google Play Services library. While this class has a send method,  it's only used for sending device to cloud messages from a device to your server.

If you don't need device to cloud messaging, you can continue to use the Sender class.